# Using expdp to backup database

Tags: oracle, backup

When I backup Oracle using this statement:

```
EXPDP userid=scott/tiger@orcl directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=%filename%.DMP
```

It has this error:

```
Ora-39002:The operation is invalid
Ora-3970:can not open the log file
Ora-39087:directory name DATA_PUMP_DIR is invalid
```

When I run:

```
select * from dba_directories;
```

The DATA_PUMP_DIR is

```
D:\app\Administrator\admin\orcl\dpdump\
```

More importantly, I created the directory by myself. It still gives the same error and I am very sure the directories exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to grant read and write permission on directory to user for taking backup.(Assuming that you have all the rights)

```
GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY data_pump_dir TO scott;
```

Comment: It is worth to add the remark that "data_pump_dir" denotes an oracle folder object (and not an OS env-var). For creating a new oracle folder object see the answer of Guna Sekaran below.

Answer (score 2):

What the error message is telling you, is that the user `SCOTT` does not have the privileges to write to `DATA_PUMP_DIR`.

As the DBA run

```
grant read, write on directory DATA_PUMP_DIR to scott;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is D:\app\Administrator\admin\orcl\dpdump\ a directory on the server? It has to be accessible from the Oracle server software to be valid, as the export actually runs on the server and not the client.

Comment: Yes on the server,the reason is have no privilege with the directory,and has bee solved,thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Error** :
ORA-39087: directory name C:\DUMP\PUB is invalid

**solution** :

grant create any directory to ATGDB_EB_PUB;

create directory YOUR_PATH as 'C:\dump\pub';

Answer (score -1):

impdp user/pass12@ETATD directory=EDWEXPORT dumpfile=NETWORK_ACTIVITY_SETT_TEMP.dmp logfile=NETWORK_ACTIVITY_SETT_TEMP.log full=y;

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sun May 12 09:42:02 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name EDWEXPORT is invalid

Comment: Can you please add explanation how this resolves the issue?